# Vizframe UI5 Pie Chart Odata Binding Issue

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, gateway, netweaver

I am trying to display a pie chart using odata binding but it's not visible in output. I can see the data in console during debugging, but chart is not getting displayed. Please find the attached view code for your reference. The table code in the view is working fine. I needs to display policy number/premium value as dimension and measure in chart. Can you please help me how to rectify it.

```
<core:View id="vw1" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="alp_report.alp" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"
xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:chart="sap.suite.ui.commons">

<Page title="ALP Report">
    <content>
        <Table id="oTable" items="{oData>/d/results}">
            <headerToolbar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Title level="H2" id="lblCount"></Title>
                    <SearchField id="searchField" width="auto"></SearchField>
                </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Policy ID"></Label>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Policy Number"></Label>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Policy Begin Date"></Label>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Journal No"></Label>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Branch"></Label>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label design="Bold" text="Policy Status"></Label>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{oData>SecpolId}"></Text>
                        <Text text="{oData>PolicynrTt}"></Text>
                        <Text text="{oData>PolbegDt}"></Text>
                        <Text text="{oData>JournalnoId}"></Text>
                        <Text text="{oData>ZzbranchCd}"></Text>
                        <Text text="{oData>ZzPolicyStatusCd}"></Text>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
        <VBox>
            <chart:ChartContainer id="chartContainer"
                showFullScreen="true" showZoom="false" title="Policy-Report">
                <chart:ChartContainerContent>
                    <chart:content>
                        <viz:VizFrame id="idpiechart" width="auto"
                            uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" vizType="pie"
                            vizProperties="{
       plotArea:{
                        dataLabel:{visible: true}
            },
                        title : {text:'Branch-Conveyance'}
        }"
                            selectData="myOnClickHandler" noDataText="Go make a Sale!"
                            renderComplete="handleRenderComplete">
                            <viz:dataset>
                                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset id="flattenData"
                                    data="{oData>/d/results}">
                                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition
                                            name="PolicynrTt" value="{oData>PolicynrTt}" />
                                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                                    <viz.data:measures>
                                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="ZztotalpremAm"
                                            value="{oData>ZztotalpremAm}" />
                                    </viz.data:measures>
                                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                            </viz:dataset>

                            <viz:feeds>
                                <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="size" type="Measure"
                                    values="ZztotalpremAm" />
                                <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="color" type="Dimension"
                                    values="PolicynrTt" />
                            </viz:feeds>
                        </viz:VizFrame>
                    </chart:content>
                </chart:ChartContainerContent>
            </chart:ChartContainer>
        </VBox>
    </content>
</Page>
```

</core:View>

Answer (score 0):

Its a type problem. for the numeric values use a custom formatter and return an number ecplictly.